# java - GC on weak reference inside map

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a following code to test GC on weak reference stored in the map.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, WeakReference<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<Person>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        Person person = new Person("weak_id"+ i, "hello"+ i, "smith"+ i, "hello@hotmail.com"+ i);
        map.put("id"+i, new WeakReference(person));
        person = null;
    }

    Map<String, Person> cache = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {
        Person person = new Person("id"+ i, "hello"+ i, "smith"+ i, "hello@hotmail.com"+ i);
        cache.put("id"+i, person);
    }

    // Make a breakpoint here and perform 'Perform GC' on the jconsole
    // and let the following code continue to see if it is discarded by GC
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        WeakReference ref = map.get("id"+i);
        if (ref == null || ref.get() == null) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(ref.get());
    }

    for (int i = 50001; i < 10000; i++) {
        Person person = new Person("later_id"+ i, "hello"+ i, "smith"+ i, "hello@hotmail.com"+ i);
        map.put("later_id"+i, new WeakReference(person));
    }

    System.out.println("hello");

}
```

I am trying to find out if GC actually reclaims memory allocated for map storing 5000 WeakReference referencing Person instance. I added 'finalize' method to the Person object and printed out each instance variable's value when GC is kicked in so that I can see the GC kicked in.

I saw the printout message when I trigger 'Perform GC' on the jconsole. I guess that it means GC reclaims memory allocated for 50000 Person instances.

But on the Eclipse debug mode, even though WeakReferences stored in the map seems to be garbage-collected, I still see the size 5000 instead of empty map.

Does it mean even though GC discards 5000 Person instances, does the HashMap still hold 5000 spaces inside the map?

Comment: The garbage collector reclaims the `Person` objects. He has no way of knowing that your `WeakReference`s are stored in a `HashMap` and therefore cannot remove neither the keys nor the `WeakReference`s from the `HashMap`

Comment: See [WeakHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) for a dictionary with Weak *Keys*: "Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys. An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. *When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map..*"

Comment: Also, consider looping over the map shown and remove keys for which the corresponding weak references no longer resolve to strong references..